# SAP integration with Xamarin?

Tags: .net, xamarin, sap-erp, saprfc

I am working on Xamarin platform. And I am looking for the integration of Xamarin with the SAP back end. So any one knows anything about this please share here.

Comment: i got some information about enosiX framework but i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used SAP in development; however, I know that you will need SAP.Net Connector. I hope these links might give you some hints:

- [SAP Integration with .Net 4.0 (SAP Connection Manager)](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/521485/SAP-Integration-with-Net-SAP-Connection-Manage)
- [Integrating SAP System With .NET Application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrating-sap-system-with-net-application/)
- [SAP ERP Integration Overview
  with Other Systems](http://cdn.ttgtmedia.com/searchSAP/downloads/SAPBasisAdmin.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to use SAP and Xamarin togheter is through ODATA.

ODATA are Rest API that you can create in SAP that permit you to execute all CRUD operations on SAP objects. In Xamarin you can simple call ODATA through http call using json or xml format.

Comment: Furthermore, your can put format into your oData link to get json instead of xml. to know more about oData http://www.odata.org/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin and SAP announced a collaboration a while ago which brought up an SAP SDK for Xamarin. You can read more on [xamarin.com/sap](https://www.xamarin.com/sap). I don't know if this project is still alive but I don't think so because the component is removed from the component store.

I found a video from a [presentation](https://xamarin.wistia.com/medias/xcak8ronxu)